# File permissions can not be changed in a Windows Linux shared folder

Tags: networking, permissions, windows-8, samba, elementary

I have created a shared folder between a windows and a Linux computer similarly as in this tutorial http://www.howtogeek.com/176471/how-to-share-files-between-windows-and-linux/. I see the files that are placed from windows in the shared folder on the Linux computer. The problem is that the folder and all the files have 755 permission. I have tried chmod and sudo chmod 777 but did not succeed to change the file permissions such that I can copy or modify the files on my Linux computer. The shared folder in the windows machine has full permissions. The only thing I did not manage to change is the read only checkbox when I right click on the folder ( it keeps setting back to read only ).

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I can tell you `chmod` definitely won't work.

Comment: yes I know,probability it must have something to do with the fact that my windows system is NTFS ...and somehow the permissions differ(for the file and the sharing) and the most restrictive permissions are chosen....

Comment: Permissions are server defined. Where exactly is your shared folder located? In Windows or Ubuntu?